# "Don't Allow access to clipboard" doesn't allow anything to be typed in the textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clipboard

I am using javascript function for copy/paste (CRTL+V) in textbox. Local run of the project works fine but if I host the project in IIS then I get a prompt saying

> Do you want to allow this webpage to access your clipboard

I know, JS function tries to read data from clipboard and hence the prompt (for security reason).

Problem is, If I click "Don't allow" then it doesn't allow me to type anything in the textbox.

Can anyone help me on this please. Any idea how to get rid of this.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Below is code sample

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsenum" runat="server" Width="300px"
onkeyup="return myFunc(event, this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

JS Function Below:

```
function myFunc(e, txtsenum) 
{
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (e.which == 86 && e.ctrlKey)
        //Some Code Here ...;
    else {
        // Some other code here ...    
    } 
   return false;   
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a browser issue instead. Try out this (for IE):

1. Go to Tools -> Internet Options.
2. Go to Security tab.
3. Select “Internet” zone, then click on “Custom level…” button.
4. Scroll down to “Scripting” section (at the bottom few).
5. Under “Allow Programmatic clipboard access” option, check or select
   (tick) Enable. Default action for this option is Prompt, which cause
   the pop-up message whenever there is any attempt to access the
   Clipboard.
6. Click Ok twice to exit from Internet Options

This [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard)  may help you more on this.

Comment: Know this already and is not what I am looking for. Link you have given ... would be helpful if using FireFox/Chrome .... but I am looking for IE workaround.